# Automated export from Windows Server to BigCommerce

Tags: windows, server, bigcommerce

I am starting a bigcommerce website and I am looking for an automated way to import csv files to bigcommerce server side. I am using windows server 2012R2, so if anybody knows how to do this, please let me know.

Comment: There's not a "bigcommerce" server to import to because it is a saas software. You can use the CSV to import against the API.

Answer (score 0):

Your title says export, but the message says import. Are you trying to do both? What data type are you trying to import/export? Products?

Comment: Yes importing and exporting product in an automated fashion